# PostgreSQL lag() not working properly with count(), but works with sum()

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT
    *,
    (src1.totals / (lag(src1.totals, 1) OVER (ORDER BY src1.x_date)) - 1) AS "Totals YOY",
    (src1.sum_yz / (lag(src1.sum_yz, 1) OVER (ORDER BY src1.x_date)) - 1) AS "sum_yz YOY"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(year FROM tbl.date) AS x_date,
        count(tbl.x) AS totals,
        sum(tbl.y + COALESCE(tbl.z, 0)) AS sum_yz
    FROM    table tbl
    GROUP BY    x_date
    ORDER BY    x_date
    ) AS src1
```

Produces a wrong Totals YOY:

```
   x_date   |  totals   |   sum_yz  |   Totals YOY  |   sum_yz YOY
    2016    |   10      |   80      |               |   
    2017    |   15      |   150     |    1          |    0.88
    2018    |   5       |   50      |    0          |   -0.67
    2019    |   25      |   500     |    0          |    9
    2020    |   25      |   500     |   -1          |    0.6
```

"Totals YOY" has a different result from the code below, even though both codes produce the same outcome. I suspect it has something to do with count() and sum(), but I don't know what.

```
SELECT
    *,
    (src1.totals / (lag(src1.totals, 1) OVER (ORDER BY src1.x_date)) - 1) AS "Totals YOY",
    (src1.sum_yz / (lag(src1.sum_yz, 1) OVER (ORDER BY src1.x_date)) - 1) AS "sum_yz YOY"
FROM (
    SELECT
        crs1.x_date AS x_date,
        sum(tbl.totals) AS totals,
        sum(sum_yz) AS sum_yz
    FROM    (
        SELECT 
            EXTRACT(year FROM tbl.date) AS x_date,
            count(tbl.x) AS totals,
            sum(tbl.y + COALESCE(tbl.z, 0)) AS sum_yz
        FROM    table tbl
        GROUP BY    x_date
        ORDER BY    x_date
        ) crs1
    GROUP BY        crs1.x_date
    ORDER BY        crs1.x_date
    ) AS src1
```

This code produces the desired outcome, but I want to get rid of that redundant level of grouping:

```
   x_date   |  totals   |   sum_yz  |   Totals YOY  |   sum_yz YOY
    2016    |   10      |   80      |               |   
    2017    |   15      |   150     |     0.5       |    0.88
    2018    |   5       |   50      |    -0.67      |   -0.67
    2019    |   25      |   500     |     4         |    9
    2020    |   25      |   500     |     0.2       |    0.6
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is probably due to the fact that the result of a `count` is a `bigint` and divisions between `bigints` result in a `bigint`

if I recreate a similar situation to yours

```
create table test (x_date int, totals bigint);
insert into test values(2016, 10);
insert into test values(2017, 15);
insert into test values(2018, 5);
insert into test values(2019, 25);
insert into test values(2020, 25);
```

The following query produced a similar wrong result as yours

```
SELECT
    *,
    (src1.totals / (lag(src1.totals, 1) OVER (ORDER BY src1.x_date)) - 1) AS "Totals YOY"
FROM test src1;
```

Result

```
 x_date | totals | Totals YOY 
--------+--------+------------
   2016 |     10 |           
   2017 |     15 |          0
   2018 |      5 |         -1
   2019 |     25 |          4
   2020 |     25 |          0
(5 rows)
```

However if I cast either the numerator or denominator as `float`, the result will correctly be a `float`

```
SELECT
    *,
    (cast(src1.totals as float) / (lag(src1.totals, 1) OVER (ORDER BY src1.x_date)) - 1) AS "Totals YOY"
FROM test src1;
```

Result

```
 x_date | totals |     Totals YOY      
--------+--------+---------------------
   2016 |     10 |                    
   2017 |     15 |                 0.5
   2018 |      5 | -0.6666666666666667
   2019 |     25 |                   4
   2020 |     25 |                   0
(5 rows)
```